# find the syntax error in JSON

Tags: json, syntax

I am trying to find the syntax error in the JSON data since an hour!

Unable to attach the full code, hence uploading in GoogleDocs

[Json.data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzr6KK9RRh-sbGY4S3VlcDZOd28)

Comment: Use http://www.jsonlint.com It isn't a correct JSON. It has 2 items in the root, however it is not a json array.

Comment: I tried, couldn't find the error jsonlint.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to efficiently find an error in a big json file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707970/how-to-efficiently-find-an-error-in-a-big-json-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is supposed to represent a single JavaScript Object, yet what you linked to includes two objects : the first object ends at line 20 and the parser would expect to reach the end of the file here, yet it finds a comma and some other data.
You might want to include these multiple objects in an array or another wrapper object.

Additionnaly, you have an extra comma after your "VPC" object, which might upset some parsers.

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I still get error "Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'", Can you wrap the two arrays and share please?

Comment: You had a ton of other errors... [here](http://pastebin.com/XLqZDnsy)'s a valid JSON close from your initial data put into an array, but you should probably not take the first thing that work and instead think about what data you need and how you want it structured. I believe the array makes no sense and that you'd better have an object whose fields are the first object (maybe called metadata), and the second the existing "Ressources" one.